# How do you find the coefficient of $x^8$ term in the expansion of $(3x^3+2x^2)^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> How would one find the coefficient of the $x^{8}$ term in the expansion of the following expression:$$(3x^3+2x^2)^3$$?

I found it by expanding out the whole expression and then finding the $x^{8}$ term but I know there is a faster way to do these type of problems. What is this method and how would I solve the problem with that method?

(The answer I got is $54$ by the way.)

Comment: You can do $(3x^3+2x^2)^3=x^6(3x+2)^3$ Then the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement) tells you the coefficient of the term of degree $8-6=2$ of $(3x+2)^3$.

Comment: Oh so do I just plug in the values into the formula($x=3x^3,y=2x^2,n=3$)?

Comment: Yes. You problem has a small enough exponent that just expanding is not much extra work, but the binomial theorem is something that you should know anyway.

Comment: Isn't binomial theorem just an easier way to expand though? I wanted a different strategy other than just expanding. Maybe I could just pinpoint the $x^8$ term in the binomial theorem? But how would I do that?

Comment: In $(3x+2)^3$ the term of degree $2$ is when $3x$ gets the exponent $2$. That is $\binom{3}{2}(3x)^2(2)^{3-2}=3\cdot 3^2\cdot 2^1\cdot x^2$.

Comment: Oh that's actually really smart, but what happens if the $x$ powers were larger? Would there be a more algebraic way to pinpoint the coefficient in the binomial theorem than noticing that $3x*3x$ has an exponent of $2$?

Comment: If the problem changes the method would have to adapt. If the exponents in $)^3$, $3x^3$, $2x^2$, or $8$ change there would be no significant change in the method.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}(3x^3+2x^2)^3 &=\binom{3}{0}[(3x^3)^3][(2x^2)^0] + \binom{3}{1}[(3x^3)^2][(2x^2)^1] +  \binom{3}{2}[(3x^3)^1][(2x^2)^2] + \binom{3}{3}[(3x^3)^0][(2x^2)^3]  
\\&=(1)[27x^9][1]+(3)[9x^6][2x^2]+(3)[3x^3][4x^4]+(1)[1][8x^6]
\\&=27x^9+54x^8+36x^7+8x^6\end{align}$

Thus, the coefficient of $x^8$ is 54.

*I expand the series by using Binomial Expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Factor:

$\begin{align*}
(3 x^3 + 2 x^2)^3
   &= \left( x^2 (3 x + 2) \right)^3 \\
   &= x^6 (3 x + 2)^3
\end{align*}$

So you want the coefficient of $x^2$ in $(3 x + 2)^3$, which is $\binom{3}{2} \cdot 3^2 \cdot 2^1 = 54$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(3x^3+2x^2)^3$$

Using the formula that the expansion's $(x+y)^n$ general term is written as $$T_{r+1}=\,^nc_r(x)^{n-r}(y)^r$$
Writing its general term;

$$T_{r+1}=\,^3c_r(3x^3)^{3-r}(2x^2)^r$$

Simplifying a little;

$$T_{r+1}=\,^3c_r(3)^{3-r}(2)^r(x)^{9-r}$$

Required coefficient of $x^8$, put in $r=1$;

$$\,^3c_1(3)^{2}(2)=(3)(3)(3)(2)=54$$